# pass json object to array - autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have two files.

```
location.php, that outputs this:

[["javascript"],["PHP"]]
```

and in another file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('location.php', function(data) {
      var sampleTags = [];

      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
         sampleTags.push(val);
         });

         alert(sampleTags); // show javascript, php


        //-------------------------------
        // Preloading data in markup
        //-------------------------------
        $('#myULTags').tagit({
            availableTags : sampleTags, // this param is of course optional. it's for autocomplete.
            // configure the name of the input field (will be submitted with form), default: item[tags]
            itemName : 'item',
            fieldName : 'tags'
        });
    });
</script>
```

the auto complete doesn't work. Why ?

if i use:

```
var sampleTags = [ 'javascript', 'php'];
```

all works well, but with json the autocomplete simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  sampleTags.push(val[0]);
});
```

should reduce [["foo"],["bar"]] to ["foo", "bar"]

Answer (score 2):

```
[["javascript"], ["PHP"]]
```

is a two dimensional array.  Your Javascript is expecting a one dimensional array.  Have your PHP output:

```
[ "javascript", "PHP" ]
```

In PHP the array should look like this:

```
array( "javascript", "php" );
```